# Verifing web app's forms with "SAVE / EXIT" before moving to next screen in between

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, customer-experience

Let's say the user is in edit scenario of a form, Now if he/she tries to visit another link by leaving the edits unsaved, is it important to show the error of "You have made an edit, do you want to save or exit without saving"

If it is, why and whats the problem is it solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Users don't like to lose (and have to re-do) work**.

This should be obvious, but a workflow that allows moving between screens without prompting to save progress will result in frustrated and irritated users.

We generally design to avoid these emotions, so alerts that warn of the risk of lost work have become commonplace.

Comment: Is this even applicable to web app's? If you can please send an appropriate link where I can have this interaction, It might help me to get more clarification.

Comment: Dude, seriously? It feels like you're trolling here. This is one of the underlying principles of working on the modern web. The only time you're not going to experience it is if the site/app is really badly designed, or if the site/app is frequently autosaving progress. On this site, start the process of asking a new question, enter some characters into and of the fields, and then click the browser back button, or click the logo to return to the homepage. You'll receive the most basic version of these interactions. "You are in mid-process, are you sure you want to leave and go somewhere else".

Comment: Thanks for the rationale, dennislees I didn't meant to troll but this was some thing our developer was bothering a lot, and I was looking an advice which might help me deal with him.

Comment: He was looking forward to try some thing which is totally irrelevant and is the prefect example of BAD UX as you said. 

Any ways, thanks for an appropriate advice/rationale for the same.

Comment: No problem. This is sounds like an example of why developers should never be allowed to make design decisions ;  )

Comment: Exactly mate :) @dennislees

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is really important to notify user that all the changes n hard work they have done will be lost if they move to another webpage. This will definitely get really irritating and frustrating for the user to make all the changes over again. Ideally, you can have an auto save feature that will automatically save all the changes.